# Setting up a destination table for a query in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, save, settings

A quick question to GBQ gurus.

I have a saved query and I want to put its' execution results to a table in my dataset. But when I open query settings there's no option for putting results to table (see pic.)

The questions are: 1) why 2) how to set a destination table for a saved query?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Why not use a scheduler for this? You can run your query and save the result to destination Table.

Comment: 'Cause I don't need a scheduler for this. I need to execute the query once and overwrite an existing table. I can't save results via "SAVE RESULTS" button, because that option does not allow to overwrite an existing table.

Comment: Hi there, @Dmitri Ilin.
Could you please check again your BigQuery web UI saved query settings? It turns out I can actually see a "destination table" field.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can simply use DDL for that: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_table_statement

Comment: Thanks for answering, that is certainly an option. But still I want to have the opportunity to set a destination table using UI.

Comment: Ever figure this out? I randomly find that I don't have this option available, and other times I do. I'm not sure what's causing it.

Comment: Actually, I just figured out what is causing it for me. The query I'm trying to save contains variables declarations. For example `DECLARE date_format STRING DEFAULT "%a, %d %b %Y %X %z";`. When I remove those declarations and update the query to not reference them anymore, suddenly all of the options to save the results to a table reappear in Query Settings. No idea why.

Comment: This is apparently expected behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60128699/why-doesnt-bigquery-ui-allow-setting-a-destination-table-if-a-query-uses-variab/60129149#60129149