# Why doesn't BigQuery UI allow setting a destination table if a query uses variables?

Tags: google-bigquery

In BigQuery, I can compose a query and then set a destination table under More > Query Settings. This works as expected for queries without variables, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM foo.bar WHERE PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%a, %d %b %Y %X %z", date_created) > '2020-01-01 00:00:00';
```

However, when I try to replace that formatting string with a variable, suddenly the options to set a destination table do not exist under More > Query Settings. For example:

```
DECLARE date_format STRING DEFAULT "%a, %d %b %Y %X %z";

SELECT * FROM foo.bar WHERE PARSE_TIMESTAMP(date_format, date_created) > '2020-01-01 00:00:00';
```

Additionally, even when I try to schedule the second query, I do not have an option to set a destination table.

Is this behavior expected? Is it documented anywhere? I have been unable to find an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

It is not because of use of parameters per se! 
But rather limitation of scripting.

So, YES, it is expected - when you use scripting you cannot use destination otherwise you will be getting error

If you need to get result into some table - just use INSERT INTO or any other relevant DML/DDL within your script

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but is this documented anywhere? I don't see it mentioned anywhere in the documentation. Why can't a destination be set when using scripting?

Comment: I haven't find a specific GCP documentation that states that you can not set destination tables when scripting. However, you may find interesting this Feature Request (not resolved yet) that requests permission to set target tables when creating scripts: https://issuetracker.google.com/147686753